# Flex item scrollable content with tailwind css

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

i'm using flex and tailwindcss with default settings.

this is my code:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqz5gavp/)

the problem is that my `main` tag, when content get full, navbar and player loose their height. and i want to make my `main` tag content scrollable without positioning absolute, just with flex. is it possible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zrsx65hn/ (added overflow-auto to fix the issue detailed in the duplicate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks